# Measure text in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm writing an app and need to paint text, It must to measure text to get point to paint. But in my knowledge, titanium don't support it. How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Measure text as in length of the text string? If your text is in a textfield you can get the .value out of it and then use string lengths to get out it's length.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is what you want;

```
var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
color: '#900',
  font: { fontSize:48 },
  text: 'A simple label',
  textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
  top: 30,
  width: Ti.UI.SIZE, height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});
win.add(label1);

label1.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e) {
    var label1_height = e.source.rect.height;
    var label1_width = e.source.rect.width;
    Ti.API.info(label1_height, label1_width);
});
```

Change the window name to yours, then run it. Should do the trick. Print the width and height of your label.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need paint multi font size, and some effect paging. How can I do that?

Comment: I used font size 48 but you can use any size. A label can only have one font size. What you could do is create the words as labels with the font size you wanted, then run through them in a for loop and position label2 at the right of label1, by getting its left coordinate and width, adding those up, then adding how ever many pixels of space you want in between.